# What is a word for a force that cannot be stopped?

Tags: nouns

A noun that can be used to describe a hurricane, or a movement. eg. "This powerful hurricane is a BLANK."

Comment: "Juggernaut" connotes some of the things you're asking for.

Comment: “Unstoppable” maybe?

Comment: The usual phrase is an **irresistible force**

Comment: Oh yes, juggernaut sounds right! thank you everyone!

Comment: Did you do any research? All you have to do is search up synonyms for unstoppable or words similar to that.

Comment: @NigelJ  was not asking you to search for juggernaut, I was asking for research in his question.

Answer (score 2):

A word with a derogatory connotation
(that refers to something *harmful*, *damaging* or *destructive*
that cannot be stopped) is ***juggernaut***:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juggernaut):
>
>   a massive inexorable force, campaign, movement, or object
>     that crushes whatever is in its path
>   - an advertising *juggernaut*
>
>     a political *juggernaut*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/juggernaut):
>
>   A huge, powerful, and overwhelming force or institution.
>   *‘a juggernaut of secular and commercial culture’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=juggernaut):
>
>   An overwhelming or unstoppable force:
>     “With the newly empowered juggernaut of the Pentagon bureaucracy
>     gaining momentum, the president was no longer in control” 
>     (James Carroll).
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/juggernaut):
>
> 1. A **juggernaut** is a very large truck.
>      [mainly British]
>
>    If you describe an organization or group as a **juggernaut**,
>      you are critical of them because they are large and extremely powerful,
>      and you think they are not being controlled properly.

The [American Heritage Dictionary entry](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=juggernaut) adds:

> ***Word History:***  For centuries, the Indian city of Puri
>   has held an annual festival in honor of the god Krishna,
>   worshiped under his Sanskrit title *Jagannāthaḥ*, “Lord of the World.” 
>   In the middle of the rainy season,
>   devotees transport highly adorned figures representing Krishna,
>   his brother Baladeva, and his half-sister Subhadra
>   from the temple where they usually reside
>   to another temple some two and a half miles away. 
>   There, Krishna enjoys the new locale until his return a week or two later. 
>   Krishna and his siblings are transported
>   in three chariots—massive towerlike structures about 45 feet high,
>   mounted on many wheels, and lavishly decorated. 
>   Thousands of devotees pull the chariots with ropes
>   and are cheered on by a crowd of over a million pilgrims. 
>   Worshipers try to obtain blessings by touching the ropes,
>   and some have been crushed in the throng or have fallen under the wheels. 
>   Early Western observers in colonial India
>   greatly exaggerated the number of these deaths, however,
>   and sensationalized reports of the incidents
>   led to the borrowing of *Jagannāthaḥ* into English as *juggernaut*,
>   “an irresistible force that rolls unstoppably over its victims.”